# Workflow Rule to Send Notification to Account Owner is not working

Tags: workflow

I am attempting to create a Workflow Rule that will send an email  notification to the Account Owner  110 before the contract end day.

Condition to be given is :

```
a)"Renewal_Status__c" is equal to pipeline ,next renewal status And 

b)when the "Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c" is not equal to renewed ,renewed lost.

c)Contact Role equal to sa/ra/ta.
```

Here "Renewal_Status__c" and "Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c" are picklist field.Contact role is a custom object which has role has picklist field and has a lookup relation with contract .
I tried creating the workflow and email alert but its not working.

**WorKFlow Criteria given :**
Workflow Rule Detail

```
Rule Name    @110 Send Email Notification    
Object    Contract
Active    Checked    
Evaluation Criteria    Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria
Description    Send email notification to the Account owner @110 days before the contract end date.
Rule Criteria    
ISPICKVAL(Renewal_Status__c , 'Pushed Forward To Next Quarter')||
ISPICKVAL(Renewal_Status__c, 'In Pipe') && Not(ISPICKVAL(Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c , 'Renewed' ) || ISPICKVAL(Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c, 'Renewal lost'))
```

**Time-Dependent Workflow Actions :**
110 Days Before Contract: Contract End Date

**Type**  :Email Alert

**Description** :@110 Email Notification to Account Owner

Email Alert :

Email Alert Detail

```
Description  :  @110 Email Notification to Account Owner   
 Email Template:    @110 Days Notification email
 Unique Name :   X110_Email_Notification_to_Account_Owner    
Object :   Contract
From Email Address :   Current User's email address         
Recipients  :  Contract Owner
Additional Emails:-
```

But the workflow is not getting triggered any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`(ISPICKVAL(Renewal_Status__c , 'Pushed Forward To Next Quarter')||
ISPICKVAL(Renewal_Status__c, 'In Pipe'))
&& Not(ISPICKVAL(Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c , 'Renewed' ) || ISPICKVAL(Next_Quarter_Renewal_Status__c, 'Renewal lost'))
&& (ISPICKVAL(Lookup_Field_Name__r.Role_Field_Name__c), 'sa') ||
ISPICKVAL(Lookup_Field_Name__r.Role_Field_Name__c), 'ra') ||
ISPICKVAL(Lookup_Field_Name__r.Role_Field_Name__c), 'ta'))`

Please validate the picklist values you are referencing. It looks like you also have (or want to have) setup a [time triggered action](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245) to send Email, so you won't see any email sent right away. Make sure that 'Contract End Date' field is populated and the date is at least 111 days from today.